# Have an if statement with 2 conditions complete a task if one condition is false

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

My code is reading in two files, comparing the lines of these files, and printing out if there is a line that doesn't match. Here's what I have:

```
while (scan1.hasNextLine() && scan2.hasNextLine())
   {
       line1 = scan1.nextLine();
       line2 = scan2.nextLine();
       if (line1 != line2)
       {
           System.out.println(lineNum1);
           System.out.println("<" + line1);
           System.out.println(">" + line2);
       }

   }
```

How do I make it so that if one of those conditions is false, ie. one file doesn't have any more lines but the other one does, it prints out letting know that the files have a different number of lines?

Thank you.

Comment: != doesn't work on objects (which strings are).

Comment: Are you allowed to use array?  if the number of lines are different, it would only print the message that the two files have different number of lines?  If so, you can build a string consisting of line ( < and > lines).  Then outside the while loop, check if scan1 or scan2 has next line.  If true, then the number of lines are different.  If false, then print the string you built.

Answer (score 0):

Different number of lines means that once your loop is finished, one scanner will be able to produce another line while the other is not.
So if either `scan1` or `scan2` returns `hasNextLine == true` you'll know that the line count is different.

Also note that `==` on objects will compare the references. You should use `!Objects.equals(line1, line2)` (null-safe) or `line1.equals(line2)` (not null-safe).

An example would look like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (var scan1 = new Scanner(Path.of("a.txt"));
             var scan2 = new Scanner(Path.of("b.txt"))) {
            while (scan1.hasNextLine() && scan2.hasNextLine()) {
                var line1 = scan1.nextLine();
                var line2 = scan2.nextLine();
                if (!Objects.equals(line1, line2)) {
//                    System.out.println(lineNum1);
                    System.out.println("<" + line1);
                    System.out.println(">" + line2);
                }
            }
            if (scan1.hasNextLine() || scan2.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println("Different number of lines");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you do not wish to output the differences in the case of different line count, you'd either have to store the result somewhere or do a count beforhand.